# Python error reading from file buffer instance

Tags: python

I am trying to read from the powerball winning numbers file:
http://www.powerball.com/powerball/winnums-text.txt

I am trying to get it line by line and I have this code:

```
import urllib.request
with urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.powerball.com/powerball/winnums-text.txt") as file:
    next(file)
    for line in file:
        line.lstrip("b'")
        line.rstrip(" \r\n'")
        print(line)
```

Each line in the file prints out like this:

```
b'12/06/1997  15  26  28  08  43  36  \r\n'
b'12/03/1997  18  09  14  47  42  32  \r\n'
b'11/29/1997  11  27  13  02  31  23  \r\n'
b'11/26/1997  15  46  34  23  40  35  \r\n'
b'11/22/1997  22  31  03  07  14  02  \r\n'
```

I am getting the error:

```
File "powerball.py", line 5, in <module>
    line.lstrip("b'")
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

I am trying to get rid of the excess characters and make the line like this:

```
12/06/1997  15  26  28  08  43  36
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you explain what it is you are exactly trying to fix and what exactly is your desired output?

Comment: @idjaw i have made changes to the post

Answer (score 3):

As someone already mentioned, the file is being read in binary mode. You need to convert the string to a text encoding format.
You can solve this with:

```
line = line.decode("utf-8","ignore")
```

This should give you the behaviour you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I **highly** recommend use use pandas for this kind of IO, it will handle the http request, the parsing, everything in a single line of code; as a bonus you can use it for your data analysis too:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('http://www.powerball.com/powerball/winnums-text.txt')
print(df)

     Draw Date   WB1 WB2 WB3 WB4 WB5 PB  PP
0     02/24/2016  67  21  65  31  64  05  3
1     02/20/2016  54  12  11  16  15  25  5
2     02/17/2016  29  27  07  40  17  25  2
3     02/13/2016  07  15  36  18  19  20  2
4     02/10/2016  02  62  40  50  03  05  2
5     02/06/2016  13  04  36  31  52  08  3
6     02/03/2016  26  60  67  31  28  23  3
7     01/30/2016  16  05  12  31  43  18  4
8     01/27/2016  40  52  03  67  12  21  2
9     01/23/2016  32  22  40  69  34  19  4
10    01/20/2016  44  05  39  69  47  24  5
11    01/16/2016  61  52  51  64  03  06  2
```

Comment: The url 'http://www.powerball.com/powerball/winnums-text.txt' is broken.  read_csv doesn't work properly with another link ''https://www.calottery.com/sitecore/content/Miscellaneous/download-numbers/?GameName=mega-millions&Order=No''

Answer (score 0):

`line` is a byte sequence, not a string. Convert it to a string using the `str` function.

```
import urllib.request
with urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.powerball.com/powerball/winnums-text.txt") as file:
    next(file)
    for bline in file:
        line = str(bline, "utf-8")
        print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> for line in file:
>     line.lstrip("b'")
>     line.rstrip(" \r\n'")
>     print(line)
> ```

You have mistaken the representation of the value, versus the value itself.

The values coming from that file are not text (`str`); they are byte sequences (`bytes`), which Python's programmer representation communicates to you by enclosing the string in `b'…'`. Those enclosing characters are not part of the value; you won't succeed in removing them.

Instead, you need to create a text string from the bytes. You do this by telling the byte sequence to decode itself:

```
for line_bytes in file:
    line = line_bytes.decode("utf-8")
    print(line)
```

This requires knowing the text codec for that byte sequence (the above code assumes “utf-8”). You can interrogate the HTTP response to ask the codec, unless you know how to get it elsewhere.

An alternative would be to open the file such that it knows its own text codec; then the items you retrieve from it would already be text.

Comment: Thank you, I have finished my program